# Run pi4j program on windows or mac

Tags: java, debugging, raspberry-pi, pi4j

I'm developing a Raspberry PI project using the Java PI4J library.
I've got it working correctly on the PI itself but am not able to run my program outside of the PI as PI4J gives errors when it runs. E.g.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/readelf": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to disable an entire library so I can try and debug other functionality of my program before I place it on the PI? Or alternatively is there a way to run PI4J so as it doesn't give these errors?

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: What operating system (for Linux, which distro) are you using?

Comment: I'm using a mac for development at the moment. I can develop in linux if needed however.

Comment: Hello Adam, how did you resolve the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new project has just started, it is not yet released, it may be unstable but it might help you.

It allows the mock up of Pi4J implementation and connect it into a simulation and modeling tools.

[www.raspinloop.org](http://www.raspinloop.org)

Fred.